# My react app only renders in one file and not when imported to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and trying to build a simple app using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks. However exporting and importing my component from *index.js* to *App.js* file and running `ReactDOM.render` in the *App.js* file causes nothing to be rendered. The component only renders when I call `ReactDOM.render` in my *index.js* file. Can someone enlighten me please. ?

Heres my index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Tours } from "./tourData";

export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <h1>Our tours</h1>
      <div className="ascent"></div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export const TourItem = (props) => {
  const { img, title, info, price, city } = props.props;
  return (
    <article className="tour-data">
      <img src={img} alt={city} />
      <div className="content">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{info}</p>
        <button>{price}</button>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

export const TourApp = () => {
  return (
    <main className="home">
      <Header />
      {Tours.map((tour) => {
        return <TourItem key={tour.id} props={tour} />;
      })}
    </main>
  );
};
```

Here's my App.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { TourApp } from "./index";

const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsloading(!isLoading);
  }, []);
  return (
    <main>
      <p>hello</p>
      <TourApp />
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Again doing this causes the app not to render at all, however if i called the render in index.js everything works fine
FYI 'Tours' is a list of objects containing vital info,etc..

Comment: yeah the `index.js` is the entry point of a react app.

Comment: i thought you could render from any file you wanted

Comment: go into `node_modules` -> `react-scripts` -> `config` -> `path.js` at around line 68 you will see that that is where the entry point is defined. it's in the `module.exports` called `appIndexJs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has more to do with the **entry** point used by your **module bundler** to start bundling all your `JS/JSX` and more files and do a couple of operations on them.

Your *App.js* consists of all the imports of your necessary components as well as the `ReactDOM.render`. But this file will not be analyzed by your bundler because it's not being imported inside the *index.js* file which is the default entry point.

If you're using `create-react-app`, that point is by default configured for you to be the *index.js* file inside their `webpack` config which is hidden from the developer unless ejected.

When building an app from scratch, you have total control over which file should be the entry file in the respective module bundler you choose.

Comment: Thank you so much read this simultaneously with https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-create-react-app-d93147444a27/#:~:text=js%20%2C%20which%20is%20the%20entry,ReactDOM.  This was a real pain to figure out